# How to evaluate foreign credential evaluation services

Tags: career-path, translations, credentials

I am considering earning a degree abroad. In order to do this it seems that I would have to hire two separate credentials evaluation firms: one to present my transcripts in the application, and later one to explain my foreign degree to my employer.

**What are best practices for hiring such a service?** Should they be able to do translation in-house, or will that definitely be a separate charge? Should they necessarily be located in the same country as the target institution?

I am aware of the U.S.'s National Association of Credential Evaluation Services; maybe many countries have such an accrediting body.

Comment: We were doing the same thing years ago. Found aan evaluation firm that would do all the paperwork etc etc for a fee of about 10k.  We went into the local government office and received all the forms (4) and lots of advice direct - all for free and it passed first time. It took us 2 evenings to complete the forms, collect copies of certificates etc.

Comment: From where to where are you trying to go? In my experience transferring degree credentials within the EU or between the EU and the US/Canada can be done relative informal with self made translations without any specific company involved. Only for some restricted professions (for example medical doctors) you need to  get foreign degrees recognized officially.

Comment: @quarague In this case, my documents would go in both directions between the U.S. and Spain. I will look again, but don't think these institutions are very flexible.

Comment: Yesterday one of my students showed me the precious transcript he had paid USD$1500 for...!!! This probably cost more than the tuition for the two-year degree that it described.